# vlc add in yocto build

Tags: build, yocto

When add vlc in yocto build using add the below line in to conf/local.conf 
`IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "vlc "`

building the yocto linux kernel there is an error saying:

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'libvdpau' (but /home/airbus/iwg27-release-bsp/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia/recipes-multimedia/vlc/vlc_2.2.2.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it). Close matches:
  libxau
  libvpx
  libpam
NOTE: Runtime target 'vlc' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['vlc', 'libvdpau']
ERROR: Required build target 'fsl-image-validation-imx' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['fsl-image-validation-imx', 'vlc', 'libvdpau']
```

Please tell me if there is anything wrong with my set up? Or if is it a issue that vlc is looking for a libvdpau but there is no such package provided in recipe?

Regards,
Subhilash K

Comment: can you share your bblayer.conf file and local.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia` for `vlc` package which directly depends on `meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia` as mentioned in [here](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-multimedia/conf/layer.conf#n30).

Package `libvdpau` is part of `meta-oe`, so add the layer `meta-openembedded/meta-oe` to your `conf/bblayers.conf` get the dependency.

You can add the layer by,

1. Manually editing the `conf/bblayers.conf` and add it to `BBLAYERS` OR
2. Use `bitbake-layers add-layer <path to meta-openembedded/meta-oe>`.